Soy iniciante en R y me piden agregar y eliminar elementos de una lista y no consigo hacerlo
Estas son las indicaciones:
mi_lista <- list(a = 1, b = "Hola", c = TRUE)
print("Lista original:")
print(mi_lista)

Agregar un nuevo elemento
mi_lista <- list(a = 1, b = "Hola", c = TRUE)
print("Lista con nuevo elemento:")
print(mi_lista)

Eliminar un elemento
print("Lista sin elemento 'xxxx':")
print(mi_lista)


Nunca hecho nada en R
pero viendo la documentación creo que seria algo así
mi_lista <- list(a = 1, b = "Hola", c = TRUE) 

print("Lista original:")
print(mi_lista)

mi_lista["d"] <- ("XS")
print("con nuevo elemento:")
print(mi_lista)

mi_lista["b"] <- NULL
print("lista sin elemento b")
print(mi_lista)

Referencia que encontré
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_lists.htm
Aquí lo probe
https://www.programiz.com/r/online-compiler/

Como alternativa a la respuesta de @CarlosCocom, podés usar la función de concatenación c() para agregar nuevos elementos a la lista. Asimismo, podés usar [ para ubicar por posición el elemento que querés eliminar.
> # agregar un nuevo elemento
> mi_lista <- c(mi_lista, d = "nuevo_elemento")
> mi_lista
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] "Hola"

$c
[1] TRUE

$d
[1] "nuevo_elemento"

> 
> #eliminar un elemento
> mi_lista <- mi_lista[-4]
> mi_lista
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] "Hola"

$c
[1] TRUE

Podés usar comparación lógica entre los nombres de los elementos y el nombre que querés eliminar:
mi_lista[names(mi_lista) != "d"]  # en este caso elimina el elemento d

